# What is the meaning of if(!b) in my code

Tags: java, boolean-logic

```
public class BooleanTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean b = true;

        if(!b){System.out.println("if");}
        else{System.out.println("else");}
    }
}
```

Here the output is else. '!' represents not. so, "if not b", what does it mean : if b not true/false?

Comment: To be pedantic, though the upshot is "if b is not true", as many said, the literal meaning is "if (not b) is true".

Comment: It basically is equivalent to `if(b == false)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically means

b == true 
!b == false

Comment: thank you everyone for such super quick response, I understood it.

Answer (score 4):

It translates as 'if `b` not true'.  The `!` operator returns `true` when passed `false`, and `false` when passed `true`.

Answer (score 4):

`!b` means the [logical negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) of `b`.

So, if `b` is `true`, `!b` is `false`, and if `b` is `false`, `!b` is `true`.
It switches between the two, so to say.

Thus,

```
if (!b) { System.out.println("!b"); }
else { System.out.println("b"); }
```

is the same as

```
if (b) { System.out.println("b"); }
else { System.out.println("!b"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way to do the same thing.

```
System.out.println(b ? "else" : "if");
```

Answer (score 0):

If b is false, it will print if.  If b is true, it will print else.

The ! flips the statement.

Answer (score 0):

`if (b)` means "if b is true".  `if (!b)` means "if b is false".  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

It simply means :

```
if(b != true){System.out.println("if");}
else{System.out.println("else");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Java operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)